# Query returns nothing when querying UserRecordAccess and filtering with ChatterMessage records

Tags: profile, query, userrecordaccess

The query in the following screenshots works fine when UserId contains a System Administrator user Id (first screenshot) but returns nothing when the user's profile is a custom one (second screenshot). The record Id belongs to a ChatterMessage record. Am I missing any profile permission? Maybe a Salesforce bug?

[image: The UserId belongs to a System Administrator user]
[image: The UserId belongs to a custom profile user]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance, that Custom Profile does not have access to Chatter or Chatter Message?

Comment: As long as I know the only permission needed would be "Manage Chatter Messages" and that custom profile has it enabled. Anyway, the query is executed as a System Administrator. If the custom profile didn't have access to Chatter Message I would expect a return anyway (something like MaxAccessLevel = None or HasReadAccess = False).